# How do I find out who is connected to ActionCable?

Tags: ruby, publish-subscribe, subscriptions, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I have seen `ActionCable.server.open_connections_statistics`, `ActionCable.server.connections.length`, `ActionCable.server.connections.map(&:statistics)`, `ActionCable.server.connections.select(&:beat).count` and the like, however this is only "per process" (server, console, server worker, et cetera).  How do I find out *everyone* who is subscribed to ActionCable at this time?  This should return the same value on any Rails process in each environment (development, staging, production).  So for example, in development console you can also see the connections on the development server since they, in theory, use the same subscription adapter (redis, async, postgres).

Rails 5.0.0.beta3, Ruby 2.3.0

related [ActionCable - how to display number of connected users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905259/actioncable-how-to-display-number-of-connected-users)

Answer (score 17):

If using `redis` you can see all the pubsub channels.

```
[2] pry(main)> Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "action_cable/*")
[
    [0] "action_cable/Z2lkOi8vbWFvY290LXByb2plL3QvUmVzcG9uXGVyLzEx",
    [1] "action_cable/Z2lkOi8vbWFvY290LXByb2plL3QvUmVzcG9uXGVyLzI"
]
```

This will show all websocket connections for all the Puma workers together. And if you have multiple servers it will probably show those here too.

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for; thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to diferenciate them , like by room or some?

Comment: @plombix please check my answer below

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba I don't see an answer below. Did you have an answer somewhere else?

Comment: Just so you know: You can decode64 the string (after the slash of course) and get something like this: `gid://myproject/User/250581` This string depends on what you use for `identify_by` I guess.

Comment: `Redis.new(url: 'redis://:auth_code@ip:port/db_number').pubsub('channels', 'action_cable/*').map { |c| Base64.decode64(c.split('/').last) }`

Comment: Use `ActionCable.server.pubsub.send(:redis_connection)` to get `ActionCable`'s Redis connection (instead of creating on your own), and `ActionCable.server.pubsub.send(:channel_with_prefix, "action_cable/*")` for the correct channel name

Answer (score 16):

To be more specific for `ActionCable` (and to Redis)...

Assuming this channel:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
end
```

Get the Redis adapter from ActionCable instead of creating it yourself
(you'd need to supply the URL from `config/cable.yml` otherwise):

```
pubsub = ActionCable.server.pubsub
```

Get the channel's name including channel_prefix you may have specified
in `config/cable.yml`:

```
channel_with_prefix = pubsub.send(:channel_with_prefix, RoomChannel.channel_name)
```

Get all connected channels from `RoomChannel`:

```
# pubsub.send(:redis_connection) actually returns the Redis instance ActionCable uses
channels = pubsub.send(:redis_connection).
  pubsub('channels', "#{channel_with_prefix}:*")
```

Decode the subscription name:

```
subscriptions = channels.map do |channel|
   Base64.decode64(channel.match(/^#{Regexp.escape(channel_with_prefix)}:(.*)$/)[1])
end
```

If you are subscribed to an `ActiveRecord` object, let's say `Room` (using `stream_for`),
you can extract the IDs:

```
# the GID URI looks like that: gid://<app-name>/<ActiveRecordName>/<id>
gid_uri_pattern = /^gid:\/\/.*\/#{Regexp.escape(Room.name)}\/(\d+)$/
chat_ids = subscriptions.map do |subscription|
  subscription.match(gid_uri_pattern)
  # compacting because 'subscriptions' include all subscriptions made from RoomChannel,
  # not just subscriptions to Room records
end.compact.map { |match| match[1] }
```

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `channel_with_prefix' for #<ActionCable::SubscriptionAdapter::Async:0x00007f2b20a45d88>)

Comment: @FavouriteOnwuemene are you using Redis? I wrote this answer is specifically for Redis. I can see that this method is still there in Rails 5.2.3 (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/actioncable/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/channel_prefix.rb), but ChannelPrefix is included in redis.rb and not in async.rb or postgresql.rb.