# Actioncable connected users list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

I'm authenticating users in ActionCable like this:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.name
    end

    protected
      def find_verified_user
        if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed[:user_id])
          verified_user
        else
          reject_unauthorized_connection
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Is it possible to get connected users list ? I googled but found only this stackoverflow questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905259/actioncable-how-to-display-number-of-connected-users), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106542/how-do-i-find-out-who-is-connected-to-actioncable)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ya kinda have to roll your own user-tracking.

The important bits are as follows:

```
# connection
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :uid

    def connect
      self.uid = get_connecting_uid
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', uid
    end

    protected

    # the connection URL to this actioncable/channel must be
    # domain.tld?uid=the_uid
    def get_connecting_uid
      # this is just how I get the user id, you can keep using cookies,
      # but because this key gets used for redis, I'd 
      # identify_by the user_id instead of the current_user object
      request.params[:uid]
    end
  end
end


# Your Channel
def subscribed
  stop_all_streams
  stream_from broadcasting_name
  ConnectedList.add(uid)
end

def unsubscribed
  ConnectedList.remove(uid)
end
```

And then in Models:

```
class ConnectedList
  REDIS_KEY = 'connected_nodes'

  def self.redis
    @redis ||= ::Redis.new(url: ActionCableConfig[:url])
  end

  # I think this is the method you want.
  def self.all
    redis.smembers(REDIS_KEY)
  end

  def self.clear_all
    redis.del(REDIS_KEY)
  end

  def self.add(uid)
    redis.sadd(REDIS_KEY, uid)
  end

  def self.include?(uid)
    redis.sismember(REDIS_KEY, uid)
  end

  def self.remove(uid)
    redis.srem(REDIS_KEY, uid)
  end
end
```

from: https://github.com/NullVoxPopuli/mesh-relay/

Comment: It seems that when restarting Action Cable server, connected_nodes won't be reset. Any workaround for this?

Comment: maybe add an initializer that clears the redis cache connected_nodes?

Comment: I believe this will also fail when a particular user connects with multiple browser windows. When the user closes one window, they'll be completed removed from the ConnectedList (since the user list is tracked using a set), even though they're still connected from another window.

Comment: then instead of adding just the uid, you'd probably want to add connected clients or number of connections from that uid in like a hash or something.

Comment: you can use a hash instead of a set, and use HINCRBY to increment/decrement the number of connections for a specific user. Then you can use HKEYS to get a list of all users