# Recording activities of every controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a log model and a method in every controller to keep record of action performed in every controller. that method populate logs modle. But i don't know how keep record of user creation, deletion and update using this function.

The method that i have created is:-

```
def keep_record(msg)
    @log = Log.new
    @log.user_id = current_user.id
    @log.description = msg
    @log.save
end
```

How can i use this method to keep record of creating, editing and removing user in devise gem.

Can anyone suggest me how to modify Registration_controller to keep record of creating, deleting and updating user.

Comment: Nothing special... can you give me any idea about how i can do that....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "track the activities", but it sounds like you want to track when a user changes those attributes. I would suggest looking into ActionCable, which the user will make a connection with, and basically subscribe to a channel, and you can record what they are doing.

Here is a good place to start:
[Actioncable connected users list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289441/actioncable-connected-users-list)