# find connected users in anycable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, anycable

There are ways to find out how many users/connections are there for action cable as asked here previously [How do I find out who is connected to ActionCable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106542/how-do-i-find-out-who-is-connected-to-actioncable) and [ActionCable - how to display number of connected users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905259/actioncable-how-to-display-number-of-connected-users).

I switched to anycable for better performance and it is working in my staging env but I don't see any pubsub keys in redis, is there a way to look into the ws server details on active connections, memory consumptions etc.

Comment: AnyCable doesn't leak any implementation details (like redis keys), so you cannot built your application on top of internal APIs (and find it broken one day after a version upgrade).




In order to track current users, you should add a kind of _presence tracking_ layer yourself.

(We plan to provide Presence APIs out-of-the-box in the future versions, though; but not right now)